What goes on in the muscle during static exercise?
Starfish opens mollusc's shell by applying static force for several hours. Mollusc gets tired and cannot hold shell closed.
Muscles spend some energy even when static exercise is done. But it is not necessary to waste energy when there is no movement.
For example, steel spring can create static force for years without with zero energy consumption.
Where does energy go in muscle during static exercise and is it possible to create "spring-like" muscle?

Looks like starfish blocks water so mollusc is starved for oxygen. It could be actually the main cause of starfish victory in this example.

The force in muscle contraction is generated by myosin cross-bridge cycling.  When a muscle contracts without shortening, this is called isometric contraction. Hypothetically, if the myosin cross-bridges could stay in a state where they are bound the to actin, then the muscle could maintain isometric contraction without expending energy. However, in skeletal muscle, myosin will continue to progress through the cycle as long as there is some ATP available, and this cycle consumes ATP. Additionally, ATP-driven calcium pumps have to be constantly moving calcium into the sarcoplasmic reticulum during isometric contraction in order to balance the flux of calcium out of the sarcoplasmic reticulum that is triggered by nerve signals. All the energy released by ATP through both processes is ultimately dissipated as heat.
Smooth muscles (like those lining blood vessels and intestines) can maintain a spring-like state, since they need to stay contracted for long periods of time. This occurs when phosphorylation of the myosin light chain prevents myosin from dissociating from the actin, so the cross-bridges stay bound to the actin. [detailed explanation]
Rigor mortis in dead animals is an example of isometric skeletal muscle contraction without energy expenditure. This happens when the muscle depletes its ATP shortly after death, so the myosin cannot un-bind from the actin.
